# How to Write UDF for Excel using ExcelDna.Addin

Tags: excel

It must be something simple that i did wrong.

All i want is write my own UDF in C# and use it in excel.
So I use Visual Studio 2019; Create Class Library C# project; Install ExcelDna.Addin ; and write a simple function; But when i build, i got the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   DNA1546 Excel-DNA is not compatible with projects that use NuGet `PackageReference`. Make sure you create a .NET Framework (Class Library) project and configure Visual Studio to use `packages.config` ClassLibrary1   C:\Users.nuget\packages\exceldna.addin\1.1.1\build\ExcelDna.AddIn.targets  69

Please Help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You likely created a class library that targets .NET Core, not .NET Framework. See the image below. The selection with the blue background is what you want.

[image: Correct project target]